# API ВКонтакте. IFrame приложение

Tags: php, javascript, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Хочу сделать самое простое приложения использующие API ВКонтакте. 
javasript у меня плох, так как специализируюсь на python и C++.
Прочитал документацию - часть понял часть нет. Из того что не понял,

1. как делать запрос?
2. как просмотреть результаты запроса?
3. и как сделать самое простоe : пользователь зашел и увидел надпись 
       " Hello %user_name% ! " 
       %user_name%    - его имя

Answer (score 4):

Всё просто там, подключаешь их библиотеку js, далее следующий код, там и запрос и вывод запроса и как раз достаёт имя и фамилию, это пример на JS:

```
<?php
    $api_secret0 = 'wFSTTMPh0'; // Секретный ключ приложения
    $idVkUser = $_GET['viewer_id']; // ID пользователя
    ?>
    <script>
var vk_id = <?=$idVkUser?>;
    var api = new vk_api('<?=$api_secret0?>','<?=$idVkUser?>', function() { 
             api.addCallback( 
               'onApplicationAdded', 
                 function() {
                 } 
             ); 
         }, 
         function() { 
         }
     );
    api.call('getProfiles', { uids: vk_id, fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'nickname'], test_mode:"1"  }, function(data) {
    var nameSaveA = data.response[0].last_name+" "+data.response[0].first_name;
    alert(nameSaveA);
       });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Без знания JS, увы, не обойтись! Да и вообще, я бы сказал, что разработка приложения для ВК - дело весьма трудоемкое. Лично у меня все закончилось на списке друзей, установивших приложение. Главная проблема - сервер на запросы отвечает с задержками иногда в несколько секунд. Так что, если будете разрабатывать, с запросами к серверу не перебарщивайте!

Answer (score 1):

Вполне можно обойтись и без JS на первое время.
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=123123&v=5.8&fields=last_seen
Разумеется чем парсить ответ по этой ссылке я думаю Вы сможете сами придумать, в php я использую curl.